# Foreign Key Constrain remains

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

MariaDB, myphpadmin

I dropped a table due to issues with creating FK constraint.  I am trying to recreate the table but it seems like the FK constraint is still in the DB somewhere.  I cannot delete as there is no reference to it, that I can see anyway.  I have no idea where to look to drop the constraint

Trying to create the table I get the following error.

```
=====================================
2020-03-04 18:58:15 0x14c6100cc700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 40 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 82 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 53679 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 53761
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 467
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 372
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 1085, OS waits 396
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 4555, OS waits 20
RW-sx spins 3, rounds 34, OS waits 1
Spin rounds per wait: 1085.00 RW-shared, 4555.00 RW-excl, 11.33 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2020-03-04 18:58:14 0x14c610081700 Error in foreign key constraint of table moviesdb/movie_genre:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT `genre_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genre` (`genre_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 237460
Purge done for trx's n:o < 237460 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 1
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 304315944137048, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 304315944132792, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
5389 OS file reads, 3086 OS file writes, 1050 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.55 writes/s, 0.20 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 69257, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
0.07 hash searches/s, 1.10 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 845237404
Log flushed up to   845237404
Pages flushed up to 845237404
Last checkpoint at  845237395
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
673 log i/o's done, 0.10 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 285212672
Dictionary memory allocated 847024
Buffer pool size   16030
Free buffers       10583
Database pages     5432
Old database pages 2018
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 5071, created 361, written 2302
0.00 reads/s, 0.10 creates/s, 0.40 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 5432, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=488, Main thread ID=22840912578304, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 820, updated 2, deleted 4, read 134187
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is right there in the log:

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table moviesdb/movie_genre
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
```

So basically this means that

- either the datatype and length of column `genre_id` in table `movie_genre` is not the same as column `genre_id` in table `genre`
- or: there is no index on `genre` (`genre_id`) (or in which `genre_id` appears first); if so, this would indicate another flaw with your table structure as, most probably, `genre_id` should be the primary key of the `genre` table.

Comment: genre_id is the PK on the genre table.  Furthermore, I've deleted the movie_genre table, so the FK constraint should not be there.  The FK constraint isn't even in the information scheme, like it doesn't exist.  I have also tried to recreate movie_genre table without genre_id and get the same error.  I have tried to recreate the movie_genre with the same attributes as genre_id in the genre table and get the same error.